# JQ: Finding array index of object with specific attribute value

Tags: arrays, select, indexing, key, jq

I have the following:

```
{"arr":[{"Name":"web"},{"Name":"app"}]}
```

I need to find out the array index of all array objects that do not have "app" in the attribute "Name".

I've tried to use a combination of "select" and "keys" but this does not work:

```
jq '.arr[] | select(.Name != "app") | keys'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one of many possibilities:

```
.arr | range(0;length) as $i | select(.[$i].Name != "app") | $i
```

And slightly more briefly but less efficiently:

```
.arr | to_entries[] | select(.value.Name != "app") | .key
```

And if you are itching to use a for-style loop, or if you want something to think about:

```
foreach .arr[] as $o (-1; .+1; select($o.Name != "app"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **tostream**.

```
      tostream
    | if   .[0][-1] == "Name" and .[1] == "app"
      then .[0][-2]
      else  empty
      end
```